# avoid routing of hash-less urls with ng-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Say, I am browsing `localhost/index.html#/view1`, and I have a link pointing to `localhost/index.html` . When I click it, angular process it through its ng-route module and it falls into my redirect clause.

this is an extract from the route config:

```
$routeProvider
    .when( "/view1", route1 )
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/view1'}); // localhost/index.html clicks fall here
```

I could use a ng-click and then redirect javascriptly with location.href, but this is not a desirable solution because I would lose the href link(SEO, bookmark, tabs).

### tl;dr

**How do I tell angularJs ng-route not to process urls without hash ?**

EDIT: I do not user html5 mode and do not plan on using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about angular routing service ignoring the url links. See documentation of `$location`

> In cases like the following, links are not rewritten; instead, the
>   browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.

Links that contain target element

```
Example: <a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>
```

Absolute links that go to a different domain

```
Example: <a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>
```

Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base is defined

```
Example: <a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! `target="_self"`  did the trick